# How to pass parameters to TestNG listeners in parallel execution?

Tags: java, selenium, parallel-processing, testng, listener

I am having a case where I have a method inside the listener which has some parameters that are different for each test case. I tried using `context.setAttribute(".....")` but that doesn't work fine. It just assigns the last value for the variable and it is being transferred to all test cases.

I have given the code below. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

```java
public class Myproject implements ITestListener{
    @Test(dataProvider = "getData")
    public static void test1(int i,ITestContext context){
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
       WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
       driver.get(url);
       context.setAttribute("driver", driver);
       context.setAttribute("testCaseNo",i+1);
       equalToOne(i);
    }
    
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] getData() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[4][1];
        data[0][0] = 0;
        data[1][0] = 1;
        data[2][0] = 2;
        data[3][0] = 3;
        return data;
    }
    public static void equalToOne(int k){
       Assert.assertEquals(1,k);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
       int i=(int) result.getTestContext().getAttribute("testcaseNo");      
       System.out.println("Testcase " + i + " Passed");     
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        int i=(int) result.getTestContext().getAttribute("testcaseNo");     
        System.out.println("Testcase " + i + " Failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        WebDriver driver=(WebDriver)context.getAttribute("driver");
        driver.quit();
    }
    
}
```

and in XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
<listeners>
       <listener class-name="testNgProjects.Myproject">
    </listener>
</listeners>
<test name="Test">
    <classes>
        <class name="testNgProjects.Myproject" />
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I should be getting output like

```
Test case 1 Failed
Test case 2 Passed
Test case 3 Failed
Test case 4 Failed
```

But the output was

```
Test case 3 Failed
Test case 3 Passed
Test case 3 Failed
Test case 3 Failed
```

It takes the last set value for `i` instead of taking different values in each tests.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the context will not solve, use the static method in your test case:

```java
org.testng.Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setAttribute(a,b)
```

and get the same values in your listeners using:

```java
org.testng.Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getAttribute(a)
```

Comment: It worked. I was searching for this everywhere. Thanks a lot man ! !

Answer (score 0):

You could have actually done this without a listener (or even context). For this particular case, just `afterMethod` would have been good. (You could have initiated and closed the `WebDriver` in `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` methods.)

Since you are running it in parallel, you could identify the specific test case using the thread itself.

```java
@Test(dataProvider = "getData")
public void test1(int i) {
    Thread.currentThread().setName(String.valueOf(i));
    equalToOne(i);
}

@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(ITestResult res) {
    String msg = "Testcase " + Thread.currentThread().getName();
    switch (res.getStatus()) {
        case ITestResult.SUCCESS:
            msg += " Passed";
            break;
        case ITestResult.FAILURE:
            msg += " Failed";
            break;
        case ITestResult.SKIP:
            msg += " Skipped";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```